# No puedo ingresar información a la base de datos

Tags: java, aplicación-web, java-ee, servlets

Estoy haciendo una simple inserción a base de datos mediante un servlet pero a la hora de correr el programa no realiza la inserción en la base de datos y se pasa directamente a la impresión de pantalla que no se pudo hacer el registro. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Les dejo mi codigo.

conexion2.java

```
package Control;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 *
 * @author Zapata
 */
public class Conexion2 {

    private String USERNAME = "root";
    private String PASSWORD = "root";
    private String HOST = "localhost";
    private String PORT = "3306";
    private String DATABASE = "registro";
    private String CLASSNAME = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private String URL = "jdbc:mysql://"+HOST+":"+PORT+"/"+DATABASE;
    private Connection con;

public Conexion2(){
    try{ 
        Class.forName(CLASSNAME);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        System.err.println("ERROR" + e);
    } catch (SQLException e){
        System.err.println("ERROR"+ e);
    }
}
 public Connection getConnection(){ 
 return con;
     }         
}
```

Consultas.java

```
public class Consultas2 extends Conexion2 {

 public boolean registrar (String nombre, String contraseña){ 
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    try {
        String registrar = "insert into usuarios (nombre, contraseña) values(?, ?)";
        pst = getConnection().prepareStatement(registrar);
        pst.setString(1, nombre);
        pst.setString(2, contraseña);

         /* if(Nombre == null && Apellido== null && Direccion== null && Imail==null && Contraseña == null && nivel == null){
            System.out.println("llena todos los campos");
    }*/
        if (pst.executeUpdate()== 1){
            return true;
           }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("Error" + ex);
    }finally{
        try {
            if (getConnection() != null)getConnection().close();
            if (pst != null) pst.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error" + e);
        }
    }
    return false;
    }
}
```

MiSErvlet.java

```
 package com.servlet;

import Control.Consultas2;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author Zapata
 */
public class MiServlet extends HttpServlet {



    /**Connection
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */

    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

         response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 

          String nombre= request.getParameter("nombre");
        String contraseña= request.getParameter("contraseña");


        Consultas2 co = new Consultas2();
        if(co.registrar(nombre, contraseña)){
            out.println("registro exitoso");
        }else{
            out.println("no se pudo registrar");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Agrega más detalles a tu pregunta, de lo contrario es más difícil que te ayuden. ¿Qué mensaje de error te sale en el código?

Comment: Por lo que veo en tu impresion en pantalla pides mas datos de los que estas pasando. ¿Podrias subir un stacktrace o una captura del error?

Comment: muestra el error que te da